# How can I make my phone synchronize data more reliably?

Tags: sony-xperia, 7.1-nougat

**Problem**

My phone, Sony Xperia Z5 Compact, doesn't like synchronizing my data.

Sometimes it takes hours for my email and chat notifications to go through, and if I take some photos, it is very reluctant in sending them to Google Photos even if my Wi-Fi is enabled with good reception and the battery is fully charged.

**Additional data**

I noticed that the problem generally disappears if I plug it into the charger, but I fail to find a setting that throttles Internet usage. The phone fails to sync even if it's fully charged and the wi-fi is on. Google Photos specifically *will* sometimes start syncing the very moment I open the app. The STAMINA and the Ultra STAMINA modes are off. The problem persists with all Wi-Fi networks I've tried, and when wi-fi is enabled during sleep.

The phone used to work normally, which makes me think either one of the software updates about a year ago caused this problem, or there's something wrong with the hardware.

**Question**

I'd like to know what I can do to make my phone sync more often and more reliably.

Comment: Does Settings > Wi-Fi > (turn on) > Menu > Advanced > Keep Wi-FI on during sleep > Always fix the issue?

Comment: @Zackary It is already set to "always". Thanks for the suggestion though.